# Why should $\nu_\mu\to \nu_e$ oscillations be expected to be unobservable in short baseline experiments?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The blog [here](http://resonaances.blogspot.com/2018/06/can-miniboone-be-right.html) says

> On the other hand, several rogue experiments refuse to conform to the standard 3-flavor picture. The most severe anomaly is the appearance of electron neutrinos in a muon neutrino beam observed by the LSND and MiniBooNE experiments.

*Within the $3$-flavour mixing and $3$-flavour neutrino oscillation scenario, why is it unlikely to observe $\nu_\mu\to \nu_e$ oscillation in short baseline ($L\leq 1$km) experiments?*

In the standard 3-flavour mixing $$P(\nu_\mu\to\nu_e)=s^2_{23}\sin^2 2\theta_{13}\sin^2\Big(\frac{\Delta m^2_{31}L}{4E}\Big)$$

Why should $\nu_\mu\to \nu_e$ oscillations be expected to be unobservable in short baseline experiments?

Comment: Did you plug in the standard measured values to get the standard expectation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugging in the implicit factor of $\hbar c$ and some conversion factors allows you to express the oscillation formula in units which are easier to calculate with:

$$P(\nu_\mu \rightarrow \nu_e) = \sin^2(\theta_{23})\sin^2(2\theta_{13})\sin^2\left(1.27 \frac{\Delta m_{31}^2}{[\mathrm{eV}^2]} \frac{L}{E} \frac{\mathrm{[km]}}{\mathrm{[GeV]}}\right)$$

The values of the mixing parameters and mass differences squared are approximately:

$$\sin^2(\theta_{23}) \approx 0.4$$
$$\sin^2(2\theta_{13}) \approx 0.08$$
$$\Delta m_{31}^2 \approx 0.002~\mathrm{eV}^2$$.

For Miniboone the distance of the detector from the target is approximately ~1 km and the energy of the neutrinos from the beam are of order 1 GeV. Plugging these in you get a value for the oscillation probability of approximately:

$$P(\nu_\mu \rightarrow \nu_e) \approx 10^{-7}$$

Since they observe ~100s of events, the probability of observing a $\nu_e$ due to neutrino oscillation is extremely unlikely.

Note that these detectors *do* expect to see some number of electron neutrino events coming from other sources. In Figure 1 from their recent paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.12028.pdf) you can see that they do expect a non negligible number of electron neutrino events from kaon and muon decays, but the anomoly referred to in the blog is that they see *more* of these events than they expect.